# change port in react project with VITE

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite, laravel-10, npm-run

I'm working on an application integrated with Laravel 10 and React JS and I'm using Vite. I changed the port in package.json in the scripts part as follows ("dev": "vite --port=3000"), but the server does not open in this port, it opens in the default port they gave me (http:// /localhost:5173) and everything I created doesn't appear. Don't know what the problem is?

I reinstalled Node_modules but I still have the same problem

Comment: I found the solution. I did not navigate to the path where the node modules are located in the react folder

Answer (score 0):

To change the port number that your react application is served from, open `vite.config.ts` or `vite.config.js` which is located at the root of your application then put

```
import path from "path"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"

export default defineConfig({
// add the below code
  server: {
    port: 5173 // change here
  },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `package.json` scripts, change your `dev` command from `"dev": "vite"` to `"dev": "vite --port 3000"`.

After you run the `dev` command, you need to go to `http://localhost/` not `http://localhost:3000`.